# Python: parse unnamed columns from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multi-index

I would like to correctly read Unnamed columns from previously generated csv file.

The csv has a multiindex header with different shape for each column, ie, say, column 0 has one coordinate, column 1 has two and column 2 has three. Thus, when reading the full csv, Unnamed columns appear in column 0 and column 1.
I need to locate a row with a given value but I cannot pass the correct column.

Imagine 'my.csv' file looks like this:

```py
C0,C1,C2
,C10,C20
,,C22
-2,0,0.4101
-1,1,0.8058
0,0,0.1000
1,3,0.3846
```

I try to read it:

```py
read_df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', header=[0,1,2]) 
print(read_df)

                  C0                 C1      C2
  Unnamed: 0_level_1                C10     C20
  Unnamed: 0_level_2 Unnamed: 1_level_2     C22
0                 -2                  0  0.4101
1                 -1                  1  0.8058
2                  0                  0  0.1000
3                  1                  3  0.3846
```

I need to select the rows corresponding to a value of C0, but I end up either in KeyError or in TypeError, such as in the following:

```py
read_df.loc( read_df[('C0','','')] == 0 )  ## KeyError: ('C0', '', '')

read_df.loc( read_df[('C0','0_level_1','0_level_2')] == 0 ) ## KeyError: ('C0', '0_level_1', '0_level_2')

read_df.loc( read_df[('C0', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2')] == 0 ) ## TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

One turnaround could be to name the columns before hand and prevent this to happen, but it would be nice to understand how to manage this.

Thanks

PS here's how I generate 'my.csv'

```py
import pandas as pd
import random as rnd

col_0 = [('C0', '', '')]
col_1 = [('C1', 'C10','')]
col_2 = [('C2', 'C20', 'C22')]

tot_col = columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col_0 + col_1 + col_2)

tot_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=tot_col)

def get_data():
    data_dict = { ('C1','C10','')    : rnd.randint(0,5),
                  ('C2','C20','C22') : '{:2.4f}'.format(rnd.random()) }
    data_df = pd.DataFrame( [data_dict], columns=tot_col )
    return(data_df)

for ii in range(-2, 2):
    ii_df = get_data()
    ii_df[('C0','','')] = ii
    tot_df = pd.concat([tot_df, ii_df], ignore_index=True)

tot_df.to_csv('my.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: `read_df['C0']` works for me. Is this the desired output?

Comment: That works for me as well.
I rather need ```read_df.loc( read_df['C0'] == 0 )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you're looking for

```
read_df.loc[ read_df[('C0', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2')] == 0 ]
```

or simply

```
read_df[read_df[('C0', 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 0_level_2')] == 0]
```

Result:

```
                  C0                 C1      C2
  Unnamed: 0_level_1                C10     C20
  Unnamed: 0_level_2 Unnamed: 1_level_2     C22
2                  0                  4  0.2373
```

---

Restoring the original index is a bit clumsy:

```
read_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple('' if y.startswith('Unnamed:') else y for y in x) for x in map(list, read_df.columns.tolist())])
```

After this you can use as usual:

```
read_df[read_df[('C0','','')] == 0]
```

Result:

```
  C0  C1      C2
     C10     C20
             C22
2  0   4  0.2373
```